# Built-in factorial function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, factorial

I know this sounds like a stupid question, but here it is: Is there a built-in factorial in Haskell?

Google gives me tutorials about Haskell explaining how I can implement it myself, and I could not find anything on Hoogle. I don't want to rewrite it each time I need it.

I can use `product [1..n]` as a replacement, but is there a true `Int -> Int` factorial built-in function?

Comment: Well, there's no "built-in" operator (i.e. part of the *standard prelude*) for factorials...

Comment: Highly unlikely. Most if not all people who need a factorial function (in any programming language) need it for an assignment/exercise, not for any real work. If one actually needs this, just hard-coding an array of all factorial numbers below `maxBound :: Int` (2**32 or at most 2**64) would be easier.

Comment: And outside prelude? I don't see why factorial can only be an exercise. It is a useful and generic operation.

Comment: For laughs, see http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Even though it is commonly used for examples, the factorial function isn't all that useful in practice. The numbers grow very quickly, and most problems that include the factorial function can (and should) be computed in more efficient ways.

A trivial example is computing binomial coefficients. While it is possible to define them as

```
choose n k = factorial n `div` (factorial k * factorial (n-k))
```

it is much more efficient not to use factorials:

```
choose n 0 = 1
choose 0 k = 0
choose n k = choose (n-1) (k-1) * n `div` k
```

So, no, it's not included in the standard prelude. Neither is the Fibonacci sequence, the Ackermann function, or many other functions that while theoretically interesting are not used commonly enough in practice to warrant a spot in the standard libraries.

That being said, there are [many math libraries available on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/#cat%3amath).

Comment: I understand this. But when you count stuff, it can be useful to have canonical functions like factorial, binomial coeffs, etc to simplify the code. I agree that you don't need this kind of functions everyday but still...

Comment: Note that `choose` is a built in function in the package Test.QuickCheck, so even though this example works whenever Test.QuickCheck is not in use it's a good practice to name it `choose'` or something totaly different.

Comment: Calculating factorial is very useful in generating permutations

Comment: @Lindhea, Test.QuickCheck may be an important package for your workflow (and others) but it doesn't own `choose`, which has been used by mathematicians for a lot longer.

Comment: @lindhe Use qualification for disambiguation, not arbitrary name extensions.

Answer (score 8):

The best implementation of factorial I know of in Hackage is `Math.Combinatorics.Exact.Factorial.factorial` in the `exact-combinatorics` package.  It uses an asymptotically faster algorithm than `product [1..n]`.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/exact-combinatorics

Answer (score 5):

No, but you can easily write one. If you are concerned about having to rewrite the function each time you need it, you could always write it as part of a module or a library (depending on how far you want to take this, any how many other similar functions you have). That way you only need to write it once, and can quickly pull it in to any other projects when you need it.

Comment: thank you. It just feels strange that haskell does not have this kind of function in a math library.

Answer (score 4):

Try Hayoo! to search (link on the top of hackage); it came up with this, for example

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/statistics/latest/doc/html/Statistics-Math.html#v:factorial

Answer (score 4):

```
fac = product . flip take [1..]
```

Comment: fac n = product [1..n]

Answer (score 2):

You have the `product` function which is in the standard prelude. Combined with ranges you can get a factorial function with minimal effort.

```
factorial n = product [n, n-1 .. 1]
nCr n r = n' `div` r'
    where
    -- unroll just what you need and nothing more
    n' = product [n, n-1 .. n-r+1]
    r' = factorial r
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fact n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * fact(n-1)
fact n = foldl(*) 1 [1..n]
fact n = product [1..n]
```

You can choose either

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a lambda expression, then you can always use the classic `fix (\f x -> if x == 0 then 1 else x * (f (x - 1)))`.

Comment: Here's [a few more ...interesting... ways](http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html) of implementing it.